# How to remove from table an event that expired with timestamp

Tags: ios, uitableview, timestamp

```
-(void)SaveUserTimeStamp:(int)timepassed addusername:(NSString *)UsernameValue {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [defaults setInteger:timepassed forKey:@"timestamp"];
    [defaults setObject:UsernameValue forKey:@"Username"];

    [defaults synchronize];
   }
```

Hi All,
I have my eventlist in tableview and when the time of this event is expired I need to remove the event from the table.Im saving my timestamp in NSUserDefaults like this. and Im calling  my this function in my eventlist like this:

```
[defaults SaveUserTimeStamp:[events.expiration intValue] addusername:events.name];
```

So ,I dont have any idea how to control this. When time is expired ,how can i check this and remove from tableview. Any idea?

Thank you in advance for your help..

Answer (score 0):

you can do a [local notification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html) to do something when the time elapsed.

Comment: Only I have in my hand timeinterval.. So how can i manage to check whether time is expired or not.? Please if you have any idea share with me?

Comment: it seems today I am not in a good mode to be a teacher, wat is obvious for me others doesn't understand even is clearly written. In this case if you open the link provided you can read about the function possibility. For example schedule a tick () when the time elapsed, and on tick() you will do your app logic: eg remove what you need to be removed. I will not provide a ready for copy-paste code, pls use your brain too a little bit

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the event from whatever data source you store them in (I guess you have an array or dictionary with events somewhere). Then use `[tableView reloadData]` and they should be gone.

How to check if an event has expired depends on how often you need to check this. You can schedule a [NSTimer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html) to check when an event has expired, but you could also have a button (or in ios6 a [UIRefreshControl](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIRefreshControl_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIRefreshControl)) to let the user refresh the view.

Comment: I couldnt get it well. Could you give an example?